# as.Date on abbreviated month (%b) with dot in Spanish locale

Tags: r, date, locale, as.date

I have a problem with R and short month abbreviations in Windows.

I just updated my PC to Windows 10, the local setting of Windows is in Spanish but R got re-configured in English (I suppose).

I have some data where the Date is in format `*"%b %d, %Y"*` and in spanish, so if the date is `January 1st 2018` it will be written like `***ene 1, 2018***`.

Before updating Windows, I didn't have any problem setting the date as:

```
as.Date("ene 1, 2018", format = "%b %d, %Y")
```

which in turn returned

> "2018-01-01"

as expected.

After the update, I had problems reading this format of dates, so if I looked at `sessionInfo()` it showed me LC_TIME=C. I changed it to Spanish with `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","Spanish")`

Now, if I write  `format(as.Date('2018-01-01'), "%b %d, %Y")` I get

> "ene. 01, 2018"*

(please note that there is a dot after the short month name)

I want to remove the dot in **ene.** because my dates are writen without dot, so now dates processed gives me *NA*.

What is a little amusing is that adding `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","Spanish")` in my code and then run it, I get the column of dates fine. But if I run it a second time, I get the `NA`. So I need to restart R if I want to run the code for a second time to get Dates and reports (using R Markdown) without error.

What configuration should I use? Or is there another solution to this problem?

If I write `sessionInfo()` I get:

> locale: LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Chile.1252 LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Chile.1252
> LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Chile.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252

Thanks!

Comment: Try something like `old_loc <- Sys.getlocale();Sys.setlocale(LC_TIME = "Spanish_Chile.1252")`. The initial `Sys.getlocale` is just to save the previous value, in case you have to reset it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer.If I write `Sys.getlocale()` the initial LC_TIME is *Spanish_Chile.1252*
For my console to actually read the Date field I need to add `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","Spanish") ` but it works only one time. To run the code again I'll need to reopen R all the time. This is because the %b in the format date is adding a dot in the month name, which is what I need to change in the configuration so it doesn't

Comment: So you don't need `Sys.setlocale`. Do you have a file named `.RData` in your working directory? If yes, maybe it's loading a previously saved configuration. Try deleting it and then restart R.

Comment: Oh, and `old_loc <- Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_TIME")` will do, you only need `LC_TIME`.

Comment: Hi Rui. Thanks again for your answer. I deleted the file but I'm still with the same error if I run the code twice.
About **old_log**, I don't get the meaning behind it.  If I restart R, the first `old_log` I get is **"Spanish_Chile.1252** for `LC_TIME`. If I run the code once, where I specify in the code  `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","Spanish")` I get the dates processed fine.  `old_log` after running the code is **"Spanish_Spain.1252"** for `LC_TIME`. If run the code for a second time, then my dates won't get well processed and `old_log` will still be **"Spanish_Spain.1252"**

Comment: Run `Sys.getlocale` **just once** and do not change `old_loc`. Apparently you don't need to change the locale, since it already is `"Spanish_Chile.1252"`, but if you do, try `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", old_loc)`.

Comment: With LC="Spanish_Chile.1252" If I type `format(as.Date('2018-01-01'), "%b %d, %Y")` R returns "ene. 01, 2018". There is a dot after the month name. That is why it returns *NA* every time I ran the code. Because of %b configuration returns a dot with the month short abbreviation. It wasn't configured like that before the actualization. Mysteriously if I set `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","Spanish")` it will read dates fine, but just one time. If I ran it again, it will read months with a dot and that is the reason I'm getting *NA*. So is a Date configuration problem I think!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with replace, cant find a better solution and im tired af

```
import locale
    
listaFechasTeorico2 = list()

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "Spanish")

date.strftime('%b-%Y').replace(".","")
```