# Getting an NA with abbreviated month format for as.Date in Spanish locale

Tags: r, date, locale, as.date

My session is in Spanish. When I have a format with full month name (`%B`) I get the correct date:

```
as.Date("01-Febrero-2021", format = "%d-%B-%Y")
# [1] "2021-02-01"
```

However, when I try to use the abbreviated month (`%b`), I get an "NA":

```
as.Date("01-Feb-2021", format = "%d-%b-%Y")
# [1] NA

as.Date("01-feb-2021", format = "%d-%b-%Y")
# [1] NA

as.Date("01-FEB-2021", format = "%d-%b-%Y")
# [1] NA
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks to the answer from G. Grothendieck, I could make it work:

```
Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
# [1] "Spanish_Argentina.1252"
```

When checking the abbreviated month using `format` on `Sys.Date`, it turns out that the month is written with a period:

```
format(Sys.Date(), "%b")
# [1] "feb."
```

Try to parse a string, this time with a period:

```
as.Date("01-feb.-2021", format = "%d-%b-%Y")
# [1] "2021-02-01"
```

Works!

Comment: Related post where they also had problems with a period (`.`) after the abbreviated month (`%b`) when using locale `"Spanish_Chile.1252"`: [Problem with as.Date %b format in short month name writen with dot R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783053/problem-with-as-date-b-format-in-short-month-name-writen-with-dot-r). Locale is a nightmare!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.  Make sure you are actually in a Spanish locale. (I am on Windows and it is possible that it works differently on other platforms.)

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
## [1] "English_United States.1252"
Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
## [1] "English_United States.1252"

format(Sys.Date(), "%b")
## [1] "Feb"
```

Now change to Spanish:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Spanish")
## [1] "Spanish_Spain.1252"
Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
## [1] "Spanish_Spain.1252"

format(Sys.Date(), "%b")
## [1] "feb"

as.Date("01-feb-2021", format="%d-%b-%Y")
## [1] "2021-02-01"
as.Date("01-Feb-2021", format="%d-%b-%Y")
## [1] "2021-02-01"
```

Comment: Thanks!! Your answer helped me. I have to use "feb." or "Feb.", with a dot at the end. I edited my question to explain this.