# Convert character do date format (Catalan): abr22

Tags: r, date, locale, lubridate

I have the following dataframe:

```
structure(list(mesos = c("abr22", "ag22", "des22"), Anual_2022 = c(66.8, 
66.8, 66.8), decil1 = c(100.1, 100.1, 100.1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I would like to convert `mesos` to date format.

So far, I have tried:

```
taxa_inflacio_ESP_mesos2022$mesos <- lubridate::parse_date_time(taxa_inflacio_ESP_mesos2022$mesos , orders = c("%m%y", "%m/%Y"))
taxa_inflacio_ESP_mesos2022$mesos<- ymd(taxa_inflacio_ESP_mesos2022$mesos)
```

But not all the values of `mesos` are converted to date format.

Comment: Why is it `ag22` and not `ago22` ? Is it not 3 letter month names?

Comment: It's in catalan... but I can change it in my excel file.

Comment: With abbreviated month names (`%b`), you may need to set your locale; see [strptime, as.POSIXct and as.Date return unexpected NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726894/strptime-as-posixct-and-as-date-return-unexpected-na)

Comment: [Getting an NA with abbreviated month format for as.Date in Spanish locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304832/getting-an-na-with-abbreviated-month-format-for-as-date-in-spanish-locale)

Comment: If you set the locale to "Catalan - SPAIN (ES)", `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "ca_ES")`, you may check the standard abbreviated month names of this locale: `format(as.Date(paste0("2022-", 1:12, "-01")), "%b")`. To parse your month names correctly, they need to have this format.

Comment: @zx8754 If you run the code in my previous comment, you find that the abbreviated month names in catalan locale is not very consistent; they may have either 2, 3, and 4 letters (followed by a period, in most cases...), e.g. `ag.` and `febr.`. There's also `jul.` and `juny`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... So I did what @Henrik said: `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "ca_ES")`
`Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` and `format(as.Date(paste0("2022-", 1:12, "-01")), "%b")`. The months in my dataset appears as they are shown with this code, but without the dot.

Comment: @Maria If you study the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304832/getting-an-na-with-abbreviated-month-format-for-as-date-in-spanish-locale) I posted above, you find that OP there describes the need for a period `.` to parse the months correctly. See also my next comment about the need for period _in most cases_.

Comment: @Henrik thanks for info, I assumed all abbr month names are 3 letters, and thought OP had a typo in their example.

Comment: @zx8754 Indeed, it seems quite tricky to remember the format(s) in that locale...